# Performance of an array grouping method

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, grouping, data-collection

Considering the date model below :

```
struct Order: Hashable {
    let mode: Mode
    let title: String
}

enum Mode {
case old, new, middle
}
```

I am using the basic swift grouping method in order to creating an array of arrays split by the mode property of the object.

```
func groupByMode(_ orders: [Order]) -> [[Order]] {
    return Array(Dictionary(grouping: orders) { $0.mode }.values)
}
```

The array below :

```
let orders = [Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt1"), Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt2"), Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt3"), Order(mode: .old, title: "shirt4"), Order(mode: .old, title: "shirt5"), Order(mode: .middle, title: "shirt6")]
```

Becomes this array of arrays :

```
let orderArrayofArrays = [[Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt1"), Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt2"), Order(mode: .new, title: "shirt3")], [Order(mode: .old, title: "shirt4"), Order(mode: .old, title: "shirt5")], [Order(mode: .middle, title: "shirt6")]]
```

This works pretty well with an array of couple of objects, but becomes longer and problematic regarding to the performances with a bigger range of data. Is that existing a way to optimize this algorithm ?

Comment: The code doesn't compile and the code doesn't produce the order of `orderArrayofArrays` regardless of the raw value type of the enum (`String` or `Int`).

Comment: @vadian check my updates the code compile

Comment: I suppose that `Dictionary(grouping:by:` is already optimized for performance.